# Merging two data frame where row duplicates

Tags: r

I have 2 data frame where the first one df1 have duplicated row. I would like to cbind it with df2 to get the desired result df3

```
>df1
 Months      A     B     C
1 Jan        4     NA     0
2 Feb        6     NA     0
3 Mar        9     NA    21
4 Jan        NA    1     NA
5 Feb        NA    0     NA
6 Mar        NA    6     NA



   >df2
 Months      D     E     F
1 Jan        1     1     0
2 Feb        2     1     0
3 Mar        3     1     0
```

I would like to merge df1 and df2, remove those duplicated rows in df1. df3 is my desired result. Thanks.

```
  >df3
 Months      A     B     C    D     E    F
1 Jan        4     1     0    1     1    0
2 Feb        6     0     0    2     1    0
3 Mar        9     6    21    3     1    0




df1 >
 structure(list(Months = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), A = c("4", "6", "9", "NA", 
 "NA", "NA"), B = c("NA", "NA", 
 "NA", "1", "0", "6"), C = c("0", "0", "21", "NA", "NA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



df2 >
structure(list(Months = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), D = c(1, 2, 3
), E = c(1, 1, 1), F = c(0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have string "NA" in your data and not actual `NA` values. Try to drop "NA" values from the columns in `df1` and then join it with `df2`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Months) %>%
  summarise(across(A:C, ~.[. != 'NA'])) %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'Months')

#  Months A     B     C         D     E     F
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Feb    6     0     0         2     1     0
#2 Jan    4     1     0         1     1     0
#3 Mar    9     6     21        3     1     0
```